# Assigning fetched NSManagedObject to a property

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest, stackmob

This question may seem long, but I'm sure it's relativity simple for Core-Data experts.  Showing  the configuration made this Question long.  Thanks!

In CoreData I have a `User` entity and an `NSManagedObject` subclass `(User.h/.m)` created from that entity.  Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using remote Database with Stackmob.

Here is what my fetch request looks like in Review.m:

Fetch Request:

```
-(NSArray *)fetchRequest
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

   //Please Note the line below:
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@", self.usernameField.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return fetchedObjects;
}


if (fetchedObjects.count>=1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Number of Objects Returned %i", fetchedObjects.count);
            NSManagedObject *fetchedObject = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-08-18 10:26:25.082 Time[995:c07] Number of Objects Returned 1
2013-08-18 10:26:25.082 Time[995:c07] User Object: <User: 0xe07b260> (entity: User; id: 0xa65ab70 <x-coredata://392983AD-D649-4D68-A93F-D86109BC009C-995-000004B584F1BB06/User/piphone5> ; data: <fault>)
```

Several weeks ago I had created the User Object successfully with the following:

```
User *newUser = [[User alloc] initIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[newUser setValue:self.usernameField.text forKey:[newUser primaryKeyField]];
[newUser setValue:self.emailAddressField.text forKey:@"email"];

[newUser setPassword:self.passwordField.text];
[newUser setValue:self.gender forKey:@"gender"];

[self.managedObjectContext saveOnSuccess:^{

    [self.client loginWithUsername:self.usernameField.text password:self.passwordField.text onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *results) {

        NSLog(@"Login Success %@",results);

    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Login Fail: %@",error);
    }];
```

This is what I would like to do in Review.m:

```
@interface Review()
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *user;
@end
@sythesize = user;
....
if (fetchedObjects.count>=1)
{
    NSLog(@"Number of Objects Returned %i", fetchedObjects.count);
    NSManagedObject *fetchedObject = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"fetchObject Object %@", fetchedObject);

    //Addition
    user = (User*)(fetchedObject);
    NSLog(@"User %@", user);
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-08-18 11:07:13.313 Time[1177:c07] Number of Objects Returned 1
2013-08-18 11:07:13.314 Time[1177:c07] fetchObject Object <User: 0xa532cc0> (entity: User; id: 0xb426de0 <x-coredata://3336122B-7117-4D92-B0A1-DDBAF80DDBF7-1177-000006EEE046E326/User/piphone5> ; data: <fault>)
2013-08-18 11:07:13.314 Time[1177:c07] User <User: 0xa532cc0> (entity: User; id: 0xb426de0 <x-coredata://3336122B-7117-4D92-B0A1-DDBAF80DDBF7-1177-000006EEE046E326/User/piphone5> ; data: <fault>)
```

Why is this not working?  User still shows up as Fault?  I have the following line in fetch Request: `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];`

The Following is the reason I need to do this:

```
Notification *notificationObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notification" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[notificationObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"appType"];
[notificationObject setValue:[notificationObject assignObjectId] forKey:[notificationObject primaryKeyField]];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext saveAndWait:&error])
{
      NSLog(@"There was an error");
}
     else
{
     NSLog(@"Notification Object Created");
}
        //I need to Add the fetchedObject as UsersObject (which is a relationship) 
        [notificationObject addUsersObject:user];
        [self.managedObjectContext saveOnSuccess:^{ ....
```

Here is my CoreData Setup:
[image]

Why is this not working?  User still shows up as Fault?  I have the following line in fetch Request: `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];`

Comment: A Core Data "fault" is a "placeholder object" and *no error at all*. The data is fetched from the database if necessary. Try logging e.g. `user.email`, it should work.

Comment: Ya, that's the only way I can get the fault to fire by accessing one of its property.  I was hoping [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]; would wokr.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that part in your question, sorry. But I made a small test with `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` and it worked as expected. - For adding the User object as a related object to the Notification object it should also make no difference if the added object is a fault or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a StackMob restriction. In https://developer.stackmob.com/ios-sdk/core-data-guide
it is explicitly stated that `returnObjectsAsFaults` / `setReturnObjectsAsFaults:`
is not (yet) supported.

Comment: Good catch! I would not have know this.

Answer (score 1):

A managed object showing up in the log as fault is fine. Use it or access its properties, and Core Data will fill the faults **in the most efficient way with a minimum strain on resources**.

This last part is important because it is the reason you don't really want to change the faulting behavior of Core Data. The necessity to send a notification does not change that.

Also, referring to the faulting section in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW6):

> Batch faulting
>
> You can batch fault a collection of objects by executing a fetch request using a predicate with an IN operator, as illustrated by the following example. [...]

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fault1, fault2, ..., nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", array];
```

> **In OS X v10.5 and later**, when you create a fetch request you can use the NSFetchRequest method setReturnsObjectsAsFaults: to ensure that managed objects are not returned as faults.

So, you see, the special fetch request shortcut is only available to OS X. Read on at above source to check out the alternative, *pre-fetching*.

Comment: But the question remains why the objects are returned as faults even if `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` is set explicitly. At least that is what the OP claims.

Comment: `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:` is also available on iOS 3.0 or later.

Comment: Not according to the above source.

Comment: I have tested it (with the iOS Simulator) and `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` works. Unfortunately, the Core Data Programming Guide is not very up-to-date.